# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. on insert / store

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes

I keep getting this error with my insert(store) page. It says

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

It happens when I go to `/category/admin/insert`

I have already tried to name my route but it didn't solve anything.

Here are my routes:

```php
Route::prefix('category')->group(function () {
    Route::post('admin/manage', 'CategoryController@destroy');
    Route::get('admin/manage', 'CategoryController@index');
    Route::post('admin/insert', 'CategoryController@store');
    Route::get('admin/edit/{id}', 'CategoryController@edit');
    Route::post('admin/update', 'CategoryController@update');
});
```

Here is my view (`.blade.php`)

```xml
<div class="card-body">
  <form action="{{ url('category/admin/insert') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" name="category_name" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Category Name">
    </div>
    <button class="form-control btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
    @if($errors->any())
      <div class="alert alert-danger mt-3">
        <ul>
          @foreach($errors->all() as $e)
            <li>{{$e}}</li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
      </div>
    @endif
    @if(Session::get('success'))
      <div class="alert alert-success mt-3">
        <strong>{{Session::get('success')}}</strong>
      </div>
    @endif
  </form>
</div>
```

and here is my `Controller`:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'category_name' => 'required|min:5'
    ]);

    $categories = new Category();
    $categories->name = $request->get('category_name');
    $categories->save();

    return redirect('/category/admin/manage')->with('success', 'Success Insert');
}
```

Comment: Do you have any redirects set up, such as HTTP -> HTTPS? Redirects only use GET, so any POST request will be changed to GET.

Comment: Do you get this issue if you type in `12345` (or something that has at least 5 characters) into your `category_name` input before submitting it? Your validation might be failing, and I'm pretty sure that causes a redirect. Edit: *"It happens when I go to `/category/admin/insert`"* - Don't go to that route; you don't have a `GET` route defined for it.

Comment: try `dd($request)` before validating request in your controller function

Comment: I just go to 127.0.0.1:8000/category/admin/insert and its always happen

Comment: Putting `127.0.0.1:8000/category/admin/insert` into your browser uses a GET request. This will not work. It's only accessible via a POST request.

Comment: Woah okay I get it. I make other controller to return db data and uses GET in route. It works :D thanks for the tips.

Comment: perhaps you want your button to be a submit button?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Don't know if it was correct or not xD but it works..

I make other controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('category.insert_category')->with('categories', $categories);
}
```

and add this route:

```
Route::get('admin/insert', 'CategoryController@create');
```